# FFMPEG | How to encode a video to make it faster

Tags: 13.04, ffmpeg

Good day people,

I was wondering how to encode a video from a speed of 1 x to a one of 5 x, using ffmpeg.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Speeding up/slowing down video**

You can change the speed of your video using ​the `setpts` video filter. The "old way" of creating timelapse or still frame was to first split up a video into individual frames, (for instance, as jpg's) then delete some and recombine the frames. Using the `setpts` filter is the new way and is faster and possibly less lossy.

To speed up your video from 1x to 5x, you can type:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf "setpts=0.2*PTS" -an output.mkv
```

Source: [FFmpeg - how to speed up / slow down a video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)

Comment: It should be worth noting that Ubuntu ships `avconv` which is somewhat incompatible to the original and not deprecated `ffmpeg`. It seems to [work fine with ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825716/unrecognized-option-filter-complex-using-avconv). As shown in the link from the answer to **speed up audio and video** the `-filter_complex` option has to be used... ***with ffmpeg***. +1 :)

Comment: Note: This does not speed up audio, only the video. Use atempo aswell for speeding the audio up. See the other answers for that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Change Video Speed

**Speed Up(5x)**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.2*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=5.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- Here, setpts=0.2, atempo=5.0

**Slow down(5x)**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=5.0*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- Here, setpts=5.0, atempo=0.2

**setpts:**

- If you want to speed up the video 2x,  setpts will be `0.5`(1/2). On the other hand, if you want to slow down the video 2x (0.5 of the normal speed), setpts will be `2.0` (1/0.5)
- If you want to speed up the video 5x,  setpts will be `0.2`(1/5). On the other hand, if you want to slow down the video 5x (0.2 of the normal speed), setpts will be `5.0` (1/0.2)

**atempo:**

- If you want to speed up the video 2x,  atempo will be `2.0`(1x2.0). On the other hand, if you want to slow down the video 2x (0.5 of the normal speed), atempo will be `0.5` (1x0.5)
- If you want to speed up the video 5x,  atempo will be `5.0`(1x5). On the other hand, if you want to slow down the video 5x (0.2 of the normal speed), atempo will be `0.2` (1x0.2)